# Update table and capture logout time on user logout

Tags: php, sql

I was tasked to make a simple volunteer checkin/out page. Volunteer picks name from dropdown clicks submit and info is submitted to mysql db, the process is the same for checkout, you pick your name from dropdown and submit and it should update table with logout time. I am having issues with the query to do this, any help or direction will be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="">

    <label >Please Select Username</label>

    <select name="userid">

    <?php
    require('db.php'); 

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * 
                               FROM users 
                               INNER JOIN check_in_out ON users.id = check_in_out.user_id ");
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<option value=". $row['id'] .">" . 
                  $row['last_name'] . ","  . $row['first_name'] . 
             "</option>";
    }
    ?>

    </select>

    <button type="submit" name="submit" >Checkout</button>

    <?php
    require('db.php'); 
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {

        $user_id = $_POST['userid'];
        $check_out_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $update_checkout=mysqli_query("UPDATE check_in_out 
                                       SET check_out_date= $check_out_date, 
                                           user_id=$user_id "); 
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
    ?>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What _issues with the query_???

Comment: You can replace `$check_out_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` just by mysql `NOW()` : http://sql.sh/fonctions/now

Comment: You either `UPDATE` an existing row using a `WHERE` clause, or you `INSERT` a new row.

Comment: my main issue is with : " $update_checkout=mysqli_query("UPDATE check_in_out SET check_out_date= $check_out_date, user_id=$user_id ");" i am would like to capture the logout time of appropriate user, i am stuck on the logic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to update :

```
$user_id = $_POST['userid']; 
$update_checkout=mysqli_query("UPDATE check_in_out 
                               SET check_out_date= NOW() 
                               WHERE user_id=$user_id");
```

1/ I remove the `date()` part and use mysql `NOW()` : see [documentation](http://UPDATE%20check_in_out%20%20%20%20%20%20SET%20check_out_date=%20NOW()%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%20user_id=$user_id)

2/ You need to use `WHERE user_id=$user_id`so you know which row you will update

3/ You should use some prepare statement instead of adding direct `$_POST` in your code : check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.prepare.php) and see why [here](http://bobby-tables.com/)